# T-SQL check constraint for .NET TimeSpan?

Tags: sql, sql-server, regex, parsing, timespan

I have a nvarchar(max) column in a sql server 2005 table which is used for storing string representations of .NET TimeSpan objects. Sometimes the table is manually edited. I want to add a check constraint to verify that the string can be parsed by TimeSpan.Parse(). How should I do this? I guess I could use one of the methods for enabling regex in sql server, but I'd like to find an easier way if there is one!

Answer (score 6):

A much better way to store .Net Timespans is in an `int` column using the TimeSpan's `.Ticks` property.

Of course, that breaks the manual table edits.  But manual table edits are evil anyway.  The best way to be sure TimeSpan.Parse() works or that you have a valid value is provide a client app using the function in question to accomplish your edits.

Finally, if you must do this try building a clr user-defined function that tests using TimeSpan.Parse().  Then see if you can include that function in your constraint (I really don't know off the top of my head if udf's (clr udf's in particular) are allowed there).

Comment: Aren't .Ticks too environment-dependent? I think storing milisseconds would be better.

Comment: A TimeSpan tick is defined as 100 nanoseconds.  Not environment-dependent.  (Unlike processor cycles, which obviously is).

Comment: `TimeSpan.MaxValue.Ticks` yields 9223372036854775807. `TimeSpan.MinValue.Ticks` yields -9223372036854775808. You MUST use `bigint` to properly store a `TimeSpan.Ticks` value.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Joel, that if at all possible you should try to get rid of the direct table edits. I'd also add that it's usually a bad idea to couple your database so tightly to your front end code like that. Store the data in a way that works best for the database and convert it as necessary for any front-end code.

If you can't, then maybe this first attempt will get you close. It doesn't allow the full precision that Timespan.Parse does because the ISDATE() function only accepts times to the nearest 1000th of a second. Maybe you can build on it though. Strip out the second fractions as I did the days and check those separately. It's a bear of an expression though.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.Test_Timespan
(
    my_string   NVARCHAR(MAX)   NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT CK_Test_Timespan_my_string CHECK (CAST(SUBSTRING(RTRIM(LTRIM(my_string)), 1, CHARINDEX('.', RTRIM(LTRIM(my_string))) - 1) AS INT) BETWEEN -10675199 AND 10675199 AND ISDATE(SUBSTRING(RTRIM(LTRIM(my_string)), CHARINDEX('.', RTRIM(LTRIM(my_string))) + 1, LEN(my_string) - CHARINDEX('.', RTRIM(LTRIM(my_string))))) = 1)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two sensible ways to store a `TimeSpan` value in SQL. As ticks in a `bigint`, which is preferred, or as a string in a varchar(26). If it is stored as 100 nanosecond ticks in a `bigint` it will naturally be limited to the appropriate number range for a TimeSpan. (`TimeSpan.Ticks` is a `long` in C#.)

If it is stored as a string, the value must fall between -10675199.02:48:05.4775808 and 10675199.02:48:05.4775807. The simplest way to validate this would be to convert to ticks. If the conversion succeeds, the value is good.

See my answer to [What is the correct SQL type to store a .Net Timespan with values > 24:00:00?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503825/what-is-the-correct-sql-type-to-store-a-net-timespan-with-values-240000) for the functions to perform TimeSpan manipulations in SQL.

Once these functions are installed the constraint can be easily created using the following code as a template that you can alter as needed:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TimeSpanStringTest](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [TimeSpanString] [varchar](26) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TimeSpanStringTest]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [CK_TimeSpanString] CHECK  (([dbo].[ConvertFromTimeSpanString]([TimeSpanString]) IS NOT NULL))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[TimeSpanStringTest] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_TimeSpanString]
GO

EXEC sys.sp_addextendedproperty @name=N'MS_Description', @value=N'Validates a TimeSpan string by trying to convert it to ticks.' , @level0type=N'SCHEMA',@level0name=N'dbo', @level1type=N'TABLE',@level1name=N'TimeSpanStringTest', @level2type=N'CONSTRAINT',@level2name=N'CK_TimeSpanString'
GO
```