# Entity Framework code first with TimeStamp type

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, entity-framework, asp.net-4.0, entity-framework-5

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 and Entity Framework 5.0. When the database is generated, I cannot add my property of type TimeStamp without having the following error:
There is no store type corresponding to the conceptual side type

> 'Edm.Time(Nullable=True,DefaultValue=,Precision=)' of primitive type
>   'Time'.

I have set the Entity Configuration to the type time or timestamp without success

```
Property(x => x.RestBetweenSet).HasColumnType("timestamp");
```

When I go in the Sql Server Management Studio and edit the table I can set a column of timestamp.

What do I need to do to have Entity Framework code first be able to generate this column?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the moment, I map to a INT64 and ignore the TimeStamp. Like in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503825/what-is-the-correct-sql-type-to-store-a-net-timespan-with-values-240000).

If they are better solutions, feel free to add. I won't accept my answer yet.

Comment: So you wanted to store a Timespan rather than a Timestamp?

Answer (score 15):

You should declare your time stamp property as follows in your code first class:

```
[Timestamp] 
public Byte[] MyTimestamp { get; set; }
```

Comment: Hi, the problem is that we cannot use anymore all timestamp method if it's a Byte.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I understand your question so well, but this how I generate `timestamp` fields using `code first` approach and  `entity framework`

```
[Required, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
```