# Get TimeSpan property in EF projection for TimeSpan converted from ticks

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm following the advice from here:

[What is the correct SQL type to store a .Net Timespan with values > 24:00:00?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503825/what-is-the-correct-sql-type-to-store-a-net-timespan-with-values-240000)

Inside a model named TimesheetEntry I have:

```
public Int64 NetLengthTicks { get; set; }

[NotMapped]
public TimeSpan NetLength
{
    get { return TimeSpan.FromTicks(NetLengthTicks); }
    set { NetLengthTicks = value.Ticks; }
}
```

I'm attempting this:

```
var shiftsData = from shift in filteredShifts
                where shift.IsDeleted == false
                select new
                {
                    shift.TimesheetShiftId,
                    shift.UserId,
                    shift.HasShiftEnded,
                    shift.StartTime,
                    shift.EndTime,
                    Entries = from entry in shift.Entries
                            where entry.IsDeleted == false
                            select new
                            {
                                entry.TimesheetEntryId,
                                entry.TimesheetShiftId,
                                entry.EntryType,
                                entry.StartTimeSpan,
                                entry.NetLength,
                            }
                };
```

I get the exception:

```
The specified type member 'NetLength' is not supported in LINQ to Entities. Only initializers, entity members, and entity navigation properties are supported.
```

I tried to change the projection to:

```
NetLength = TimeSpan.FromTicks(entry.NetLengthTicks)
```

but that gave the exception:

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.TimeSpan FromTicks(Int64)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

I then tried creating an expression to do the conversion:

```
public static Expression<Func<DAL.Models.TimesheetEntry, TimeSpan>> NetLengthExpression
{
    get
    {
        return e => TimeSpan.FromTicks(e.NetLengthTicks);
    }
}

// in the projection
NetLength = NetLengthExpression
```

But that threw:

```
The LINQ expression node type 'Lambda' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.
```

Is there a way to expose NetLength as a TimeSpan to be returned in my query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do a conversion on the database side unless EF knows how to do the conversion, and it sounds like EF doesn't know how to do this conversion.

You'll have to use a helper method to do the conversion.

I usually handle this kind of situation with a helper method on my `DataContext` class because, if I'm doing a query, then I usually have an instance of that class to work with.

```
public class DataContext : DbContext {
    public TimeSpan GetTimeSpan(Int64 ticks) {
        return TimeSpan.FromTicks(ticks);
    }

    // ... other code
}
```

**Edit**

This might also be an option:

```
var shiftsData = from shift in filteredShifts
                where shift.IsDeleted == false
                select new
                {
                    shift.TimesheetShiftId,
                    shift.UserId,
                    shift.HasShiftEnded,
                    shift.StartTime,
                    shift.EndTime,
                    Entries = from entry in shift.Entries
                            where entry.IsDeleted == false
                            select entry
                };
```

If you get rid of the anonymous class created by your query and simply `select entry`, you'll get an instance of your `Entry` class, which will populate your `NetLengthTicks` property and let you use your `NetLength` getter. Be aware, though, that you may be selecting more rows than you actually need if you project an instance of the class.

Comment: That's not really any different than my already existing wrapper property. Using a GetTimeSpan method in my projection throws: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.TimeSpan GetTimeSpan(Int64)'... I know the conversion works after the query has resolved, but I'm trying to do this in the projection since I will be returning a collection of entries inside a collection of shifts. To do a nested ForEach on the results and apply the conversion on the results is slow and ugly.

Comment: @mbursill - But you don't have an instance of `Entry` because you're creating an anonymous class with the query, so you can't use the wrapper property without instantiating an instance of `Entry`. If you change `select new...` to `select entry`, you'll get an instance of your `Entry` class, and you'll be able to use the `NetLength` property. But doing so may return more rows than you really need.