# Which Sql Server column type to use for a position in a video?

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework

So I want to store a value that represents something like "10 minutes and 35 seconds into the video".  I was going to use the type `time`, but my value could be greater than 24 hours.  My data would probably always be formatted hours:minutes:seconds.

Also, I'm using Entity Framework so I need some type that will translate well. Thanks.

Comment: IMHO it would be better to just stick to a simple numerical type such as `INT` and save the smallest unit possible/necessary (and have the representation of that value handled by the displaying client/frontend); so in your case that would probably be seconds or milliseconds or maybe even more precise just simply the number of frames into the video.

Comment: Related:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503825/what-is-the-correct-sql-type-to-store-a-net-timespan-with-values-240000

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I have questions like this I try to find "*what are the pros doing?*"

If you go to YouTube and share the video at current time you'll see they add a Query Parameter t=10 (10 seconds into the video).

So I would use **int** .

Comment: Or, if seconds can be fractional, choose a numeric type with the proper precision and scale.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a VARCHAR and do some formatting as you read the values out.