# milli/nano seconds not inserted into the time[7] field when using TimeSpan

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database, timespan

I'm using the following insert query to insert a time duration of type `TimeSpan` (the `duration` variable) into a field in my table that has a `time[7]` value. The INSERT is successful but it only inserts up to the seconds even though the duration has nano values they are always 0000000. How can I insert the exact duration?

```
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(cs);
string sql = "UPDATE CampaignRun SET Duration=?,FtpResult=?,FtpCommand=?,Report=? WHERE CampaignId=?";
using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.Add("Duration", OleDbType.DBTime).Value = duration;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("FtpResult", OleDbType.Boolean).Value = ftpStatus;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("FtpCommand", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ftpCommand;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("Report", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = ReadListbox();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("CampaignId", OleDbType.BigInt).Value = campaignId;
    conn.Open();
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();
}
```

[image]

Comment: And what is the value of `duration` when you insert it?

Comment: Can it be that OleDbType.DbTime does not support it? Why are you even considering using OleDbConnection to connect to a sql server instead of the native SqlConnection?

Comment: @Dirk {00:00:00.2232904}

Comment: @TomTom I usually use OleDb without a problem but if this is really the issue I can use an SqlConnection instead.

Comment: According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.data.oledb.oledbtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx): `DBTime: Time data in the format hhmmss (DBTYPE_DBTIME). This maps to TimeSpan.` As ms and ns are not included in that format string I would say this behavior is expected.

Comment: For saving values with your required precision you might want to consider just [saving the TimeSpan.Ticks-Property which is BIGINT and from which you can easily rebuild the original value](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8504020/2186023)

Comment: @DrCopyPaste I think I will go with the bigint and just save ticks instead.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation of [`OleDbType.DBTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Time data in the format hhmmss (DBTYPE_DBTIME). This maps to TimeSpan.

This would indicate that fractionals of seconds aren't supported.