# SQL CLR User Defined Function that returns Nullable<TimeSpan>

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server-2008, user-defined-functions, sqlclr

I'm trying to return a Nullable from a SQL CLR User Defined Function, but when i compile i get the following error:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [ReadCell_Time] (@rowData [xml], @columnName [nvarchar](4000))
RETURNS /* Error: Unsupported type. */
AS EXTERNAL NAME [UserDefinedFunctions].[ReadCell_Time];
GO
```

The code of my function is:

```
public static TimeSpan? ReadCell_Time(SqlXml rowData, SqlString columnName)
{
    var data = rowData.GetValue(columnName);
    return data.IsNull ? null : (TimeSpan?)TimeSpan.Parse(data.Value);
}
```

I'm using SQL Server 2008, Visual Studio 2013 and my project uses C# target .NET Framework 3.5 with UNSAFE permission.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have a data type that models a time span - it has the `time` type but that models a *time of day*, not a *time span*.

Comment: Though you can store and retrieve timespans in SQL Server, simply store the Ticks as bigint in the DB, ref. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503825/what-is-the-correct-sql-type-to-store-a-net-timespan-with-values-240000

Comment: SQL Server map TimeSpan to TIME, but when i use Nullable<T> to allow null return it fails.