# How to use > between datetime data type in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table where I am inserting `StartTime` and `EndTime`. Now after insertion I want to add a check where if `EndTime > StartTime` than add `EndTime - StartTime` into another column which is `TimeEntered`. This stored procedure runs without any error but the column value remains as `NULL`.

My table design and stored procedure are as following:

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IX_TaskStatistics]
(
    [StatisticsID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [RequestId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [WorkspaceId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RequestSource] [nvarchar](4) NOT NULL,
    [Stats] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    *[TimeEntered] [datetime] NULL,*
    **[TimeStart] [datetime] NULL,
    [TimeEnd] [datetime] NULL,**
    [ConceptCount] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [DocumentCount] [bigint] NOT NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

My stored procedure: (Updated)

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE IX_TaskStatistics_Insert
@RequestId bigint, @WorkspaceID int, @RequestSource VARCHAR(50),@StartTime datetime, @EndTime datetime, @ConceptCount bigint, @DocumentCount bigint
AS
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO ix_taskstatistics 
                (requestid, 
                 workspaceid, 
                 requestsource, 
                 timestart, 
                 timeend, 
                 conceptcount, 
                 documentcount, 
                 timeentered) 
    VALUES      (@RequestId, 
                 @WorkspaceID, 
                 @RequestSource, 
                 @StartTime, 
                 @EndTime, 
                 @ConceptCount, 
                 @DocumentCount, 
                 CASE 
                   WHEN @EndTime > @StartTime THEN (SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Datediff(s, @StartTime, @EndTime)/3600) 
                         + ':' 
                         + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), Datediff(s, @StartTime, @EndTime)%3600/60) 
                         + ':' 
                         + CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), (Datediff(s, @StartTime, @EndTime)%60)) AS timeentered) 
                 END) 
END 
GO
```

Result :

```
StatisticsID  RequestId WorkspaceId RequestSource Stats TimeEntered              TimeStart               TimeEnd                 ConceptCount DocumentCount
------------- --------- ----------- ------------- ----- ------------------------ ----------------------- ----------------------- ------------ -------------
1             6265      7           CCD           NULL   1900-01-01 00:00:01.000 2015-03-25 10:24:37.323 2015-03-25 10:24:38.713 4             97
```

EXPECTED RESULT :

```
StatisticsID  RequestId WorkspaceId RequestSource Stats TimeEntered   TimeStart               TimeEnd                 ConceptCount DocumentCount
------------- --------- ----------- ------------- ----- ------------- ----------------------- ----------------------- ------------ -------------
1             6265      7           CCD           NULL  00:00:01      2015-03-25 10:24:37.323 2015-03-25 10:24:38.713 4             97
```

Comment: You're doing two inserts, and the second one should fail. It looks like you meant to perform an update but you can also do that inline in the insert using a CASE expression.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I've updated my store proc as you suggested but I want output in `[hh:mm:ss]` format and now it is coming as a `datetime`. I tired `replace(Convert (varchar(8),GetDate(), 108),':','')` and `select convert(varchar, getdate(), 108)` but didn't work.

Comment: *tried. sorry about the misspell in earlier comment.

Answer (score 0):

SQL does not have a good way to store timespans (the time difference between two dates). There is the [`time`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx) datatype but that only works for up to 24 hours. I give you the same advice I would give a [.NET developer trying to store a time span](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503825/what-is-the-correct-sql-type-to-store-a-net-timespan-with-values-240000), store the value in some time independent format. When you go to display this value do the math to transform it to the `hours:minutes:seconds` at the GUI layer not the database layer.

So now TimeEntered is just a `bigint` that counts seconds.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IX_TaskStatistics]
(
    [StatisticsID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [RequestId] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [WorkspaceId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [RequestSource] [nvarchar](4) NOT NULL,
    [Stats] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    **[TimeEntered] [bigint] NULL,**
    [TimeStart] [datetime] NULL,
    [TimeEnd] [datetime] NULL,
    [ConceptCount] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [DocumentCount] [bigint] NOT NULL,
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
```

And your stored procedure changes to

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER PROCEDURE IX_TaskStatistics_Insert
@RequestId bigint, @WorkspaceID int, @RequestSource VARCHAR(50),@StartTime datetime, @EndTime datetime, @ConceptCount bigint, @DocumentCount bigint
AS
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO ix_taskstatistics 
                (requestid, 
                 workspaceid, 
                 requestsource, 
                 timestart, 
                 timeend, 
                 conceptcount, 
                 documentcount, 
                 timeentered) 
    VALUES      (@RequestId, 
                 @WorkspaceID, 
                 @RequestSource, 
                 @StartTime, 
                 @EndTime, 
                 @ConceptCount, 
                 @DocumentCount, 
                 CASE 
                   WHEN @EndTime > @StartTime THEN DATEDIFF(second, @StartTime, @EndTime)
                 END) 
END 
GO
```

Now `timeentered` holds the number of seconds between the two times. When you go to display this value to the user or use it in the program you can format any way you need at that point.

Comment: Make sense. Rather doing this in DB it will be easier to perform calculation in code behind to display the required format.