# How to Save TimeSpan value in database in "d.hh:mm:ss" format?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

```
TimeSpan timeInDays= new TimeSpan(2,8,8,8);
```

i want to save "timeInDays" in DB using EF. Table column is of type "Time".
It gives me run time exception,

> "SqlDbType.Time overflow.  Value '2.08:08:08' is out of range.  Must
>   be between 00:00:00.0000000 and 23:59:59.9999999."

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct SQL type to store a .Net Timespan with values > 24:00:00?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503825/what-is-the-correct-sql-type-to-store-a-net-timespan-with-values-240000)

Answer (score 3):

As @Mainul says, the `time` type has a range of 24 hours at the most. To store longer time periods I recommend using `bigint` (a 64-bit integer) that can be used to represent a timespan value directly. See this QA for more details: [What is the correct SQL type to store a .Net Timespan with values > 24:00:00?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503825/what-is-the-correct-sql-type-to-store-a-net-timespan-with-values-240000)

If you can't change the table schema then you'll have to truncate data, one approach is to lose less-significant bits by shifting to the right before saving to the DB (and then left-shifting when loading), but this will be messy:

The `time` type in SQL Server by default is `time(7)` (7 decimal digits of precision) which uses 5 bytes, see here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx - so we need to shift the binary representation of a timespan ("ticks"), which uses 8 bytes, to the right by 3 bytes (to get 5), which is 24 bits. Illustrated below:

```
TimeSpan tick value (64-bits): 0x01 0x23 0x45 0x67 0x89 0xAB 0xCD 0xEF
SQL Server time field        :                0x01 0x23 0x45 0x67 0x89
```

As TimeSpan Tick store their most-significant bits on the left, it means the three bytes that we will lose (`0xAB 0xCD 0xEF`) represent tiny fractions of a second that we can afford to lose that aren't worth worrying about. When we load the data back from the DB and left-shit it back by 3 bytes it will look like this (note the three `0x00 0x00 0x00` bytes that have lost their values):

```
TimeSpan tick value (64-bits): 0x01 0x23 0x45 0x67 0x89 0x00 0x00 0x00
```

#### Saving:

```
TimeSpan tooBig = new TimeSpoan( 2, 8, 8, 8 );
Int64 tooBigBits = tooBig.Ticks;
Int64 truncated = tooBigBits >> 24;
TimeSpan temp = TimeSpan.FromTicks ( truncated );

yourDbEntity.timeValue = temp;
```

#### Loading:

```
TimeSpan temp = yourDbEntity.timeValue;
Int64 truncated = temp.Ticks;
Int64 adjusted = truncated << 24;
TimeSpan actual = TimeSpan.FromTicks( adjusted );

yourDbEntity.timeValue = actual;
```

Answer (score 2):

> In T-SQL, Time type column Defines a time of a day. The time is without
>   time zone awareness and is based on a 24-hour clock.
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx

Your `TimeSpan()` method return time including day value for which it is greater than a 24 hour value. **What you can do is, save the time value without the day value.**

**EDIT:** If you want to subtract the day value from current TimeSpan.

`new TimeSpan(timeInDays.Hours, timeInDays.Minutes, timeInDays.Seconds)`

Answer (score 1):

You could store your time as a `DateTime` (02.01.0001 08:08:08) in the db and still use the time for your project

```
public class Task
{
    [NotMapped] 
    public TimeSpan Duration
    {
        get { return Duration2 - DateTime.MinValue; }
        set { Duration2 = DateTime.MinValue + value; }
    }

    public DateTime Duration2 { get; set; }
}
```

This has the disadvantage that you can't make database queries based on `Duration`

```
var tasks = from t in tasks where t.Duration > TimeSpan.FromHours(50);
```

but you have to use

```
var duration = DateTime.MinValue + TimeSpan.FromHours(50);
var tasks = from t in tasks where t.Duration2 > duration;
```

Or you could store seconds instead of a date value in your database with the same concept.

Comment: It should be DateTime2. And in EF queries the part `DateTime.MinValue + TimeSpan.FromHours()` should be stored in a variable first.

Comment: @GertArnold No it shouldn't be DateTime2, we are talking about .NET DateTypes.
I changed my code to first assign the value to a variable.