# Get SQL Server DATEDIFF column as a TimeSpan when using SqlDataAdapter

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqldataadapter

Is it possible to get the result of the DATEDIFF function in SQL Server as a TimeSpan when filling a DataTable using `SqlDataAdapter`?

As a very minimal example:

```
var table = new DataTable();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"select DATEDIFF(mi, '2016-01-01', '2016-02-02') as [foo];", conn);
var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
da.Fill(table);
Console.WriteLine(table.Columns[0].DataType);
```

This prints out `System.Int32` instead of `TimeSpan`, and I can't change the DataType after the table has been already filled with `table.Columns[0].DataType = typeof(TimeSpan);`, because it would throw an exception.

I could create an entirely new DataTable and copy the data into it, but I'd rather not do that.

Comment: You can cast to `time` if the difference is less than 24 hours.

Comment: You can also get the TimeSpan value by subtracting `DateTime.MinValue` from the DateTime value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just define it before select:

```
    var table = new DataTable();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"select DATEDIFF(mi, '2016-01-01', '2016-02-02') as [foo];", conn);
    var da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    table.Columns.Add("foo", typeof(TimeSpan));
    da.Fill(table);
    Console.WriteLine(table.Columns[0].DataType);
```

**EDIT**

but be careful. you are using DATEDIFF with mi parameter. but when you maps foo to TimeSpan it means that timespan will be created with this amount of minutes interpreted as Ticks.

So to correct it you need to do something like this

```
select DATEDIFF(mcs, '2016-01-01', '2016-02-02')*10 as [foo]
```

Since ticks is 100 nanosecond units.

but in most cases it will cause to `SqlException: The datediff function resulted in an overflow.`

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server doesn't have a data type that maps automatically to a .Net `TimeSpan`.  You usually have to store the span as an Int (or BigInt) and convert it to a `TimeSpan` as you read from the adapter.

Check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503825/what-is-the-correct-sql-type-to-store-a-net-timespan-with-values-240000) for some examples.

Comment: "as you read from the adapter" - that's what I'd like to do, but are there any hooks or callbacks or virtual methods in `SqlDataAdapter` that would allow me to do the conversions while reading?

Comment: I found about FillSchema from http://stackoverflow.com/a/9028126/492336, I think that would be the solution.

Comment: I think for the datatable, you have to have the non-TimeSpan column from the adapter, and then you can fill/add another TimeSpan column based off the db value

Comment: There is no need for conversion, just subtract DateTime.MinValue from the resulting DateTime column. This can be added as a calculated column to the datatable

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this may help.  This is a modified version my my AGE function  which returns Years, Months, Days, Hours, Minutes, and Seconds.

The TimeSpan function was scaled down to Days, Hours, Minutes, Seconds, and Milliseconds.

It may look like overkill, but it is very accurate, and being a Single-Statement TVF, it is very fast.

Being a TVF, you can used as stand-alone, within a Join, or even a Cross Apply

For Example:

```
Select * from [dbo].[udf-Date-TimeSpan] ('2016-07-29','2016-07-30 02:03:12.345')
```

Returns

```
TimeSpan        Days  Hours Minutes Seconds Millisecond
1.02:03:12.348  1     2     3       12      348
```

The Function if Desired

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[udf-Date-TimeSpan] (@D1 DateTime,@D2 DateTime)
Returns Table
Return (
    with cteBN(N)   as (Select 1 From (Values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) N(N)),
         cteRN(R)   as (Select Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL))-1 From cteBN a,cteBN b,cteBN c,cteBN d,cteBN e),  -- Max 100K Days or 273 Years
         cteDD(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(DD,R,@D1))From cteRN R Where DateAdd(DD,R,@D1)<=@D2),
         cteHH(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(HH,R,D))  From (Select Top 24 R From cteRN Order By 1) R, cteDD P Where DateAdd(HH,R,D)<=@D2),
         cteMI(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(MI,R,D))  From (Select Top 60 R From cteRN Order By 1) R, cteHH P Where DateAdd(MI,R,D)<=@D2),
         cteSS(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(SS,R,D))  From (Select Top 60 R From cteRN Order By 1) R, cteMI P Where DateAdd(SS,R,D)<=@D2),
         cteMS(N,D) as (Select Max(R),Max(DateAdd(MS,R,D))  From (Select Top 999 R From cteRN Order By 1) R, cteSS P Where DateAdd(MS,R,D)<=@D2)

    Select TimeSpan  = concat(cteDD.N,'.')+Format(cteHH.N,'00:')+Format(cteMI.N,'00:')+Format(cteSS.N,'00')+'.'+Format(cteMS.N-1,'000')
          ,[Days]    = cteDD.N
          ,[Hours]   = cteHH.N
          ,[Minutes] = cteMI.N
          ,[Seconds] = cteSS.N
          ,[Millisecond] = cteMS.N-1
     From  cteDD,cteHH,cteMI,cteSS,cteMS
)
--Select * from [dbo].[udf-Date-TimeSpan] ('2016-07-29','2016-07-30 02:03:12.345')
```

Edit - Perhaps a better illustration

```
Declare @Table table (Date1 Datetime,Date2 DateTime)
Insert Into @Table values
('2016-01-01 00:00:00.200','2016-01-05 12:05:01.500'),
('2016-01-01 10:00:00.300','2016-01-05 12:30:30.500'),
('2016-01-01 10:00:00.800','2016-01-05 12:30:30.500')

Select A.*
      ,B.TimeSpan
 From @Table A
 Cross Apply [dbo].[udf-Date-TimeSpan] (A.Date1,A.Date2) B
```

Returns

```
Date1                       Date2                       TimeSpan
2016-01-01 00:00:00.200     2016-01-05 12:05:01.500     4.12:05:01.300
2016-01-01 10:00:00.300     2016-01-05 12:30:30.500     4.02:30:30.200
2016-01-01 10:00:00.800     2016-01-05 12:30:30.500     4.02:30:29.700
```