# How to get the time duration from subtracting two times

Tags: c#, winforms, datetime, duration

I have userTransact table that contains the (login and logout) time and date , now I used these codes for the duration calculation but the problem is that it subtarct dates also giving me invalid date as follows:
login 2016-12-22 08:28:27.540
logout 2016-12-22 08:28:32.947
duration 1900-01-01 00:00:05.407
How to fix this problem?
The codes for this calculation are in the FormClosing event as:

```
SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("insert into empTransLogin(empLogTransNo,empId,logTimeIn,logTimeOut,duration) VALUES (@logTrans,@id,@login,@logout,@duration)", cn);
cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@logTrans", x);
cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", deleteById);
cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login", loginDateTime);
cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@logout", DateTime.Now);
TimeSpan duration = DateTime.Now - loginDateTime;
cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@duration", duration);
cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("delete from empLogin where empId=" + deleteById + "", cn);
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
Application.Exit();
```

Comment: How should look `duration`? When you do `logout-login` you will get `TimeSpan` from this you can get duration time in seconds, tics or what you want

Comment: Please don't use `AddWithValue`. It is likely to create problems: [Best Practices - Executing Sql Statements](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/.net/3589/ado-net/14261/best-practices-executing-sql-statements).

Comment: @M.Wiśnicki the duration should by the full date then the full time, here the time is correct but the date is not .. it should be the same date if the user logged in and logged out at same day.

Comment: @Tima'aTamim That isn't what a duration is. You've misunderstood the concept.

Comment: @john you mean that the duration is only time?
if so then can you modify the code to use only time?

Comment: Do what I suggested in my answer. See this, too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503825/what-is-the-correct-sql-type-to-store-a-net-timespan-with-values-240000

Comment: The duration should be a time Which has expired from date login. So you should consider change parameter for store `duration`. Just keep seconds

Comment: Do you really need to store the duration. Except if you do queries based on the duration like finding longest or shortest login time, you would be better not to store that column.

Answer (score 2):

```
SqlCommand cmd3 = new SqlCommand("insert into empTransLogin(empLogTransNo,empId,logTimeIn,logTimeOut,duration) VALUES (@logTrans,@id,@login,@logout,@duration)", cn);
cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@logTrans", x);
cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", deleteById);
cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@login", loginDateTime);
cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@logout", DateTime.Now);
TimeSpan duration = DateTime.Now - loginDateTime;
cmd3.Parameters.AddWithValue("@duration", duration.TotalSeconds);
cmd3.ExecuteNonQuery();
SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand("delete from empLogin where empId=" + deleteById + "", cn);
cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
Application.Exit();
```

Be aware that TotalSeconds isn't an integer value.

Comment: the time in my code is determined perfectly the problem was with the date look to the duration 1900-01-01 00:00:05.407

Comment: What type are you saving Duration as in the database? How are you getting this value with year, month, etc. since duration isn't a date type?

Comment: the type is datetime in database

Comment: Store it as seconds. You're getting this strange value because you're trying to put a timespan into a datetime, which aren't really comparable types.

Comment: I altered the datetime data type to time only and I get this result
login 09:26:54.8600000
logout 09:27:01.0030000
duration 00:00:06.1423513

Comment: Store login and logout as datetime, since that's the date type you're using. Store duration as seconds, as provided by TotalSeconds. Simple. KISS.