# Invalid TimeSpan cast in Microsoft.SqlServer.Server

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I would to know how to make it works since it is throwing InvalidCastException:

I have tried using `DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay`, but I got the same error.

[image]

Stack trace:

```
em Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.ValueUtilsSmi.SetTimeSpan(SmiEventSink_Default sink, ITypedSettersV3 setters, Int32 ordinal, SmiMetaData metaData, TimeSpan value, Boolean settersSupportKatmaiDateTime)
   em Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlDataRecord.SetTimeSpan(Int32 ordinal, TimeSpan value)
   em Matematica.UI.Areas.Professor.Controllers.ListasController.ObterTurmas(List`1 agendamentos) na C:\Users\murilo\Source\Repos\moderna-matematica\Matematica.UI\Areas\Professor\Controllers\ListasController.cs:linha 127
   em Matematica.UI.Areas.Professor.Controllers.ListasController.Agendar(AdicionarAgendamento agendamento) na C:\Users\murilo\Source\Repos\moderna-matematica\Matematica.UI\Areas\Professor\Controllers\ListasController.cs:linha 112
   em lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   em System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   em System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   em System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   em System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
   em System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   em System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End()
   em System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   em System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d()
   em System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f()
```

Comment: A sql server timestamp is more of a version number than an actual time. It's C# equivalent data type is `byte[]` or a byte array.

Answer (score 1):

A SQL Server [Timestamp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776(v=SQL.90).aspx) is not a timestamp per se. It's just an incrementing number, used for row versioning.  Storing a `DateTime` or a `TimeSpan` in that column is not possible.

If you want to store a timespan in the database, your best bet is to convert it to a common format, such as elapsed seconds, and store it as an integer.  See [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503825/what-is-the-correct-sql-type-to-store-a-net-timespan-with-values-240000) for more information.