# What is appropriate type in SQL for C# type TimeSpan

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have class which has property type of TimeSpan.

At some point I need to store value properties in database.

For this purpose I need to create appropriate table in database so i wonder what is appropriate type in SQL for C# type TimeSpan?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8503825/1070452  also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings

Answer (score 3):

There's no direct mapping, but it would probably make the most sense to use a `bigint` column and store the [`Ticks`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.ticks%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) property of `TimeSpan`.

To store data into the column, use `TimeSpan.Ticks`.  To extract data out of the column, use `new Timespan(ticks)`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how precise you want to be: seconds, milliseconds, minutes, hours. Whatever works. I suppose you could do ticks if you need that kind of precision.