# Saving TimeSpan to Time in SQL without days

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, timespan

I saving `TimeSpan` valus to a `Time(7)` column in a SQL Server table. I have a problem when values of days in `TimeSpan` become 1, I got this error:

> System.OverflowException: SqlDbType.Time overflow. Value '1.00:00:00' is out of range. Must be between 00:00:00.0000000 and 23:59:59.9999999.

How can I ignore the days part in a `TimeSpan` when I save it to `Time(7)` column?

Comment: `time(7)` is not an appropriate data type to store a `TimeSpan`. `time(7)` stores a time of day. `TimeSpan` stores **the length of a period of time**. While they _seem) similar, they aren't anywhere near the same thing. e.g. you can't store a `TimeSpan` of 25 hours in a `time(7)`.

Comment: I would ask myself the question how it is possible that the value is bigger or equal to 1.00:00:00. This indicates your timespan is over a day, this is not possible when you are only interested in time between 0 and 24 hours.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the correct SQL type to store a .Net Timespan with values > 24:00:00?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503825/what-is-the-correct-sql-type-to-store-a-net-timespan-with-values-240000)

Comment: Not a duplicate: the linked question asks "how to store values > 24h", this one asks "how to ignore days".

Answer (score 0):

You could simply create a new timespan with the days set to 0.

```
ts = new TimeSpan(0, ts.Hours, ts.Minutes, ts.Seconds, ts.Milliseconds);
```

Comment: ... and you might also want to consider that a `TimeSpan` can be negative, so that this could still result in a value that's out of range.  Also this truncates fractional milliseconds, you could avoid this by using `ts.Add(TimeSpan.FromDays(-ts.Days))` instead.