# Each 15 minutes i need calculating amount using Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i am creating a simple Intenet cafe management System using vb.net.this my final year project every thing gone fine. at the final stage of project i faced the problem of when person sit on the computer time is started it is working fine i attached sceen shot below. each 15mins i need calculating amount 50 i don't how to do it. what i tried so far i attached below.

[image]

```
    Private _elapseTimerRunning As Boolean = False
    Private _elapseStartTime As DateTime




    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Timer1.Interval = 1000
        Timer1.Enabled = True
    End Sub

    Dim hr, min, sec As Integer

    Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        txtTime.Text = Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt")
        If _elapseTimerRunning = True Then
            Dim elapsedtime = DateTime.Now.Subtract(_elapseStartTime)
            txtElapsed.Text = String.Format("{0}hr : {1}min : {2}sec", elapsedtime.Hours, elapsedtime.Minutes, elapsedtime.Seconds)

            If (elapsedtime.Minutes > 15) Then
                Label1.Text = "50"
            End If

        End If
    End Sub


    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        _elapseStartTime = DateTime.Now
        _elapseTimerRunning = True
    End Sub


    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        _elapseTimerRunning = False
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You can create a second timer with the 15 minutes interval.

Comment: how to do it sir second timer with the 15 minutes interval.

Comment: i just create the  second timer with the 15 minutes interval

Comment: then how to  set

Comment: Now create a global variable to keep the amount. Increment by 50 that variable every second timer tick. Assign the value of the variable to the label showing the amount due

Comment: sir i don't how to write code

Comment: Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
        Label1.Text = "50"
    End Sub        like this way sir i wrote the code inside the timer 2

Comment: Dim a As Integer = 50   a = a + 50   Label1.Text = a     i wrote inside the Timer2.Tick it won't work sir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this code gives you any ideas. I added a stop watch to the mix to track total elapsed time. I upped the timer interval to 10 seconds. Each time the `DateDiff` exceeds 15 minutes the `CumlativeValue` is incremented the label text is updated and the `StartTime` is reset to `Now`.

```
Private StartTime As DateTime
Private CumlativeValue As Integer
Private sw As New Stopwatch

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Timer1.Interval = 10_000
    Timer1.Enabled = True
    StartTime = Now
    sw.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    Label2.Text = sw.Elapsed.ToString
    If DateDiff(DateInterval.Minute, StartTime, Now) > 15 Then
        CumlativeValue += 50
        Label1.Text = CumlativeValue.ToString
        StartTime = Now
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you sir your are best. i have one doubt how to add time elasped in to server machine

Comment: if i click the stop button how to stop i wrote the code below time is stop but CumlativeValue += 50 is not stoped    wrote like this     sw.Stop() please help me

Comment: To stop things use `sw.Stop` and `Timer1.Enabled` = False. To store `sw.Elapsed` which is a `TimeSpan` in Sql Server use a `BigInt` and `sw.Elapsed.Ticks`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503825/what-is-the-correct-sql-type-to-store-a-net-timespan-with-values-240000  Then to turn it back to a TimeSpan use TimeSpan.FromTicks(value)

Comment: Best develperrrrrrrrr