# How to store times more than 24 hours in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sqldatatypes

My question is what data type in SQL Server suitable for times more than 24 hours? `Time` data type as Microsoft said is for less than 24 hours:

```
Range   00:00:00.0000000 through 23:59:59.9999999 
(00:00:00.000 through 23:59:59.999 for Informatica)
```

So for example if I have course table and duration of some course is more than 24 hours, what should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the correct SQL type to store a .Net Timespan with values > 24:00:00?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503825/what-is-the-correct-sql-type-to-store-a-net-timespan-with-values-240000)

Comment: `time` is more designed only to store a time, not a period of it. If you want to store details of a duration, you're better off storing a numerical value that details how many of the smallest denominator you'll need (i.e. seconds), or the start and end times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Represent the course duration in seconds (or minutes) if you prefer.  If you want to then represent the value as HH:MM:SS, it gets a little tricky, but you can cobble it together:

```
select concat(dur / (60 * 60), ':',
              format((dur / 60) % 60, '00'), ':',
              format(dur % 60, '00')
             )
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6b2ccfc523ef5895beb1612d49c276c9) is a db<>fiddle.

You can even add this as a computed column into the table, so the string representation is always available.