# DBContext object LINQ Sum(time) column to hours

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

This is an ASP.Net Core Web API Project, using EntityFrameWorkCore.
I need to convert TotalLoggedInTime (format: 139:05:40) to Hours and Sum the hours and assign it to logonHours, it fails on that line.
The first line for callsOffered works fine.

C# Code:

```
internal void Hydrate(DbSet<MyObj> myObj)
{
    string callsOffered = myObj.Sum(a => a.CallsPresented).ToString();
    string logonHours = myObj.Sum(a => TimeSpan.Parse(a.TotalLoggedInTime).TotalHours).ToString();
}
```

SQL Table

```
SELECT total_logged_in_time FROM mytable

total_logged_in_time
139:05:40
157:22:46
157:26:51
148:17:42
157:23:14
138:04:28
175:27:41
162:35:44
163:13:13
144:36:12
9:01:56
```

Error

> The LINQ expression 'TimeSpan.Parse((EntityShaperExpression: 
>       EntityType: MyObj
>       ValueBufferExpression: 
>           (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)
>       IsNullable: False ).TotalLoggedInTime).TotalHours' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated,
>   or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to
>   either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or
>   ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for
>   more information.

Solution:

Using the solution provided by @Arcord.
I had to add an extension method for converting the hours, but that's beyond the scope of this original issue.

```
string logonHours = myObj.ToList().Sum(a => a.TotalLoggedInTime.ToHours()).ToString();

public static double ToHours(this string valueInTimeFormat)
{
    double hours = 0;

    //hours = TimeSpan.Parse(valueInTimeFormat).TotalHours;

    int[] ssmmhh = { 0, 0, 0 };
    var hhmmss = valueInTimeFormat.Split(':');
    var reversed = hhmmss.Reverse();
    int i = 0;
    reversed.ToList().ForEach(x => ssmmhh[i++] = int.Parse(x));
    hours = (int)(new TimeSpan(ssmmhh[2], ssmmhh[1], ssmmhh[0])).TotalHours;

    return hours;
}
```

Comment: Is it okay to read the rows from the database and do the `Sum()` calculation in C# and not in the database?

Comment: What's up with the reversing, the extra ToList, the ForEach+callback and the closure over (and modification of) `i` in your extension method?? `new TimeSpan(int.Parse(hhmmss[0]), int.Parse(hhmmss[1]), int.Parse(hhmmss[2]))` would do the trick. `ToList().ForEach()` is an anti pattern--many people abuse `ToList` on an enumerable just to call `ForEach` instead of iterating normally with `foreach`. We wrote an analyzer to disallow it in our code base

Comment: @Progman I tried that, but since the data in time format could be like this 155:32:58, it's failing, throws this error in sql.
Operand data type datetime is invalid for sum operator.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33  I didn't actually pay attention to it, I had to quickly get it done, so I copied it from stackoverflow. It didn't make sense but it worked so I moved on. But you're right, it could be simpler. I'll fix it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because it tries to convert your code to SQL.

```
string logonHours = myObj.Sum(a => TimeSpan.Parse(a.TotalLoggedInTime).TotalHours).ToString();
```

Of course everything is not convertible to SQL so in that case it fail.

You can use this :

```
string logonHours = myObj.ToList().Sum(a => TimeSpan.Parse(a.TotalLoggedInTime).TotalHours).ToString();
```

It should works **but** the ".ToList()" will force EF to fetch all data from the database and then (since everything is in memory) the code can be applied.

But only do this if you have a small amount of data! It's better not to put that kind of stuff in production if you don't know the expected load.

**Edit**

You could also also considers to store "ticks" instead of a string (like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503825/what-is-the-correct-sql-type-to-store-a-net-timespan-with-values-240000)). In that case you will the able to do.

```
string logonHours = TimeSpan.FromTicks(myObj.Sum(a => a.TotalLoggedInTime)
```

More work will be done on the SQL server and you will only gather the sum.

You should also considers to use "async" version of methods (ToListAsync, SumAsync, ...)

Comment: I get this error now, it's the same format, not sure why it would fail.
The TimeSpan string '157:26:51' could not be parsed because at least one of the numeric components is out of range or contains too many digits.

Comment: This data is from Cisco box as xlsx file, and imported into SQL Server. I probably should convert it to ticks during the import process.

Comment: Instead of `ToList` it's better to use `AsEnumerable` that way you don't create an intermediate list that gets thrown away.

Comment: It's because you cannot create a timespan of more of 24h... So "24:12:45" will fail but not "1:00:12:45" will work (24h became 1 day). I'm afraid you will have to modify a little bit your code. You could maybe split the string, parse to int each part and convert it to seconds ?