# The LINQ expression could not be translated about sum of Property TimeSpan

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1, timespan

I have a table named CourseEpisode that have different property , one of them is TimeSpan

```
   public TimeSpan time{ get; set; }
```

when i trying to get sum of Episod Time with this code :

```
    var TotalTime = new TimeSpan(c.CourseEpisods.Sum(e => e.time.Ticks))
```

when i run my project i face with this Error :

> InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression '(EntityShaperExpression:
> EntityType: CourseEpisod
> ValueBufferExpression:
> (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember)
> IsNullable: False
> ).Time.Ticks' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(),ToList(), or ToListAsync()

please help me

Comment: your problem is very similar to the question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62457480/dbcontext-object-linq-sumtime-column-to-hours
basically Ticks property is only available in C# TimeSpan, there's no corresponding concept in SQL so EF is not able to translate that to SQL. You need to call ToList() to bring everything back and do Sum from C# client code

Comment: What database type are you targeting? e.g. SqlServer  etc.

Comment: @PhuongNguyen First, you don't know how `TimeSpan` is mapped in database. For instance, SqlServer EFC provider maps it to `time`. And while there are no `Ticks`, it has milliseconds (microseconds and even nanoseconds) which should be enough. Thar's why for EF Core the question is what database type is targeted. Switching to client evaluation is a last resort.

Answer (score -2):

here is an example

```
void Main()
{   
    var table = new List<TimeSpan> 
                {
                    new TimeSpan(1,0,0),
                    new TimeSpan(0,30,0),                   
                    new TimeSpan(2,0,0),
                    new TimeSpan(0,0,10)
                };
                
    
    TimeSpan total = TimeSpan.Zero;
    table.ForEach(t => total = total.Add(t) );  
    
    Console.WriteLine($"Total Duration Is  = {total.ToString()}");
}
```

Then you get

```
Total Duration Is  = 03:30:10
```

Comment: Working with list (memory collection) and database are totally different things, hence your example is out of context  (useless).